# How to check http url connectivity of webview in every 2 second in android native

Tags: android, webview, error-handling, monitor

I have a webview running on android native application. I need a polling service which ensures that webview's http url status code is 200 otherwise throws an error. And once connectivity is back with status code 200 error dismisses. Basically internet connection is available but there is a server communication error

I relied on onReceivedError() method which was called on error with http and async task was performed by passing url to check if status was 200. But onReceivedError() was getting called after 30sec - 1min even after connection was lost.

Expected: As soon as connection is lost and http url is not accessible error should be displayed immediately

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the following steps-

1. Create (not call) an android background service and put a timer with recursive methid. In the method create a http url connection to your url and check status code.
2. Create a broadcast receiver connecting to your activity having the webview.
3. In the service when the status code is not 200 ping the broadcast receiver.
4. In the webView activity on broadcast receive perform your task.